# Verify what the user entered

Tags: ada

I am a beginner in Ada programming and I have the following code :

```
PROCEDURE ask(variable: OUT myType) IS
BEGIN
   Put("Enter : ");
   Get(variable);
   Skip_Line;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS => RAISE wrongInput;
END ask;
```

This procedure asks to enter something and put it in my "variable" variable (which type is myType containing characters from '1' to '3').

I raise an exception when the input is not correct.

Now I would like to do something else when the input is 'm' for example.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that `myType` is declared as something like

```
subtype myType is Character range '1' .. '3';
```

You can write the output into an unconstraint `Character` variable, then check it:

```
PROCEDURE ask (variable : OUT myType) IS
   Input : Character;
BEGIN
   Put ("Enter : ");
   Get (Input);
   Skip_Line;
   CASE Input IS
      WHEN 'm' =>
         RAISE gotM;
      WHEN OTHERS =>
         -- this will raise Constraint_Error if the value is not
         -- in range '1' .. '3'
         variable := Input;
   END CASE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS => RAISE wrongInput;
END ask;
```

I used `case` instead of a simple `if` because it sounds like there may be other input values added in the future. Now while this is technically possible, I consider it bad style, because it uses the exception `gotM` for implementing non-exceptional behavior. You should re-think your code layout so that you don't have a procedure `ask` that can only return `'1' .. '3'` but needs to handle other input, too.

Comment: Ok I see, however as you said it´s not a good programming style. So I'm going to re think my procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Change the declaration of `myType`:

```
type myType is ('1', '2', '3', 'm');
```

Comment: This will not work with `Ada.Text_IO.Get`, you'd have to use `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion` from `Character` to this type or use one of the more powerful I/O packages.

Comment: `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion` is going to lead to a lot of grief unless there's also a representation clause on `myType`.  Without the rep clause, it would convert ASCII.NUL to '1', ASCII.SOH to '2', etc., and the actual '1', '2', '3', 'm' characters to invalid values.  In fact, `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion` doesn't do any checking (surprise!), so even with a rep clause it would be a big problem if an invalid character were entered (although `'Valid` could be used).  `Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO` (on `myType`) would expect the single quote marks around the enumerations, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps? (just guessing here, "I would like to do something else" is extremely vague).

```
procedure Ask (Variable : out My_Type) is
begin
   loop
      begin
         Put ("Enter :");
         Get (Variable);
         Skip_Line;
         return;
      exception
         when others =>
            Skip_Line;
            Put_Line ("invalid.");
      end;
   end loop;
end Ask;
```